# I can't display large number in arduino

Tags: c, arduino-ide

I am trying to make a project with arduino and when I input plank's constant in the code h=6.26E-34 and trying to display it it displays zero ?

My Code :

```
double h=6.626E-34;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

 Serial.println( h);
 delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that `Serial.println()` isn't displaying enough digits of accuracy. With `printf()` I got it to work like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double d = 6.626e-34l;
    printf("%.40f\n", d);
}
```

I think with `Serial.println()` the following should work: (Don't have an arduino handy to test it on)

```
Serial.println(h, 40);
```

http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println Says that the 2nd parameter to `Serial.println()` for floats will set the decimal accuracy.